# How to display function based view endpoint in django rest frameworks

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am having a hard time to understand how to display function based views URLS with Django REST FRAMEWORK.

I have the setup below of my project but for some reason I am unable to display the endpoint while MovieListViewSet works.

PROJECT.URLS

```
from users import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', MovieListViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('profile/', views.ProfileList, name='ProfileList')
]
```

users.model

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            #'bio',
            #'location',
            'image',
        )
```

I have comment `bio` and `location` because when they are uncommented, I receive this message.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bio` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bio'.
```

users.views (app)

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def ProfileList(APIView):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am unable to see ProfileList view as endpoint

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong to display this endpoint to django rest framework.

Comment: have you tried **`/profile/`**? What you mean by *"unable to see ProfileList view as endpoint"* ?

Comment: @JPG it does access the URL but no data is returned. what I mean is that I what to see the Profile of each user listed on that endpoint like you would normally using a router.

Comment: Does your **`Profile`** model has data/objects?

Comment: @JPG yes it does but currently nothing is returned unless I go to `Admin` to see the data

Comment: can you add **`ProfileSerializer`** class?

Comment: @JPG I just added it, along with the models.py

Comment: checkout the answer below.

Comment: @JPG it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify **`many=True`** while serialization.

```
serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, many=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up functions and class based view definition here:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def ProfileList(APIView):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Either you define a class based view like this:

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = ProfileSerializer

    def list(request):
       return Response(self.serializer_class(self.get_queryset(), many=True).data)
```

Or a function base view like:

```
@api_view(["GET])
def profile_list(request):
   return Response(ProfileSerializer(Profile.objects.all(), many=True).data)
```